# Sending the document and window objects from chrome.runtime.sendmessage

Tags: javascript, html, json, dom, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension to fetch any JSON object in the pageSource of HTML document. So, for this I need to get the document object , and also window object from the chrome.runtime.sendMessage.

If I am sending the window object as below I am getting an ****circular structure to json** error.

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
   'title': document.title,
   'url': window.location.href,
   'summary': window
});
```

And I am retreiving the above values through a callback function,

```
function onPageDetailsReceived(pageDetails)  { 
    document.getElementById('title').value = pageDetails.title; 
    document.getElementById('url').value = pageDetails.url; 
    document.getElementById('summary').value = pageDetails.summary;
} 

window.addEventListener('load', function(evt) {

    chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function(eventPage) {
      eventPage.getPageDetails(onPageDetailsReceived);
    });
});
```

Can anybody tell me how to get the document element as well as window element from the above function.

Comment: Why exactly you need the `window` object passed to the background page?

Comment: I have a Json object confiured in the window object. Need to retrieve that object

Comment: Well, I mean why exactly you need to send the entire `window` object instead of extracting the data and sending just the data? Do you know that sendMessage stringifies everything and this might be slow for complex objects?

Comment: Unfortunately, sending the window object isn't possible.